# Extract residuals from Uhlig's rejection method - Lag selection

Tags: time-series, r

I wanna determine the number of lags for a Baysian VAR/FAVAR model, which I implement based on R's VARsignR package. To compute the AIC/BIC I'd need the residuals of the model estimation. How can I extract these to compute the two selection criterion? There is no such object provided as part of uhlig.reject.

```
model <- uhlig.reject(Y= data, nlags=3, draws=200, subdraws=200, nkeep=1000, KMIN=1,KMAX=2, constrained=constr, constant=FALSE, steps=25)
```

Later I wanted to compute the criteria according to:

```
BIC <- function(model) {
  
  ssr <- sum(model$residuals^2)
  t <- length(model$residuals)
  npar <- length(model$coef)
  
  return(
    round(c("p" = npar - 1,
          "BIC" = log(ssr/t) + npar * log(t)/t,
          "R2" = summary(model)$r.squared), 4)
  )
}
```

Any thoughts on this? Is there maybe a smarter way for lag selection in this context? Papers are pretty vague here.

Comment: I don’t have time right now to write full answer but I think you could just use varsoc. If I am not mistaken varsoc command estimates auxiliary var based on data and gives you nice overview of optimal lags by all common criteria (aic, bic etc)